# Routes in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I used scaffold to create a model and controller. It worked well. Then I started editing/removing some of the controller actions. So I made participations/new > participations/signup.

This does not work, it says "Unkown action" but it does say it has the action signup. Funny thing is if I go to Participations/signup using a capital P. Then it does work!

I also did Rake routes where participations/new still shows up even though I edited the method name.

IS there anything special I need to do to define actions?

Answer (score 4):

You need to edit the config/routes.rb file, too and tell Rails how should it handle the participations/signup route. In your routes.rb file you should have something like:

```
map.resources :participations
```

you will have to add a new rule for this:

```
map.signup '/participations/signup', :controller => 'participations', :action => 'new'
```

Tha should do it.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using resources then it is quite easy to fix.

that is, if you have

> `map.resources :participations`

and you don't want to use named routes like the other answers suggests, you have the following options:

- To change the /participations/new to
  /participations/signup, but still
  keep the new as the action in the
  controller

  > `map.resources :participations, :path_names => {:new => 'signup'}`
- To use /participations/signup, and the action signup in the controller:

  > `map.resources :participations, :collection => {:signup => [:get, :post]}`

If you also want to limit so that they can't use the /participations/new action, add `:except => :new` to the above statement

I suggest that you use this way unless you have a reason for using the named routes since it (at least it's my opinion) gives a cleaner routes.rb.

Just keep in mind that the routes.rb are being read from top till bottom, so the first matching route will be the one being used.

Answer (score 1):

It's not unusual to maintain the standard RESTful routes and controller actions and map user-friendly alternate paths onto them. For example, in your case:

```
map.signup '/signup', :controller => 'participations', :action => 'new'
```

Your users could then access `participations#new` at the very friendly URL `http://foo.com/signup` (if, of course, your site were at foo.com). In your controllers and views you would refer to this route as `signup_path` or `signup_url`.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, RoR is case sensitive, so make sure your controller starts with a lowercase "p" and any actions also start with a lowercase letter. give that a try